# Xamarin Forms Android project image not displaying but displays correctly on iOS

Tags: android, ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am able to display an image without an issue when I run the iOS project however when I run the Android project the image does not appear no matter what.

I have triple checked that the image which is located in Resources/drawable folder has its build action set to AndroidResource, I have also attempted to define the source via both XAML and in C# which works every time on iOS and never on Android.

I am able to display the default icon.png that comes with the project without issue.

In XAML

```
<StackLayout>
             <Image Margin="0,0,0,75" x:Name="Header"/>
             <Image x:Name="Jumbo"/>
</StackLayout>
```

In C#

```
        Header.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("mblogo.png");
        Jumbo.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("MBMural.jpg");
```

Again the file is located in the Resources/drawable folder under the Android project and the files are set to the build action "AndroidResource".

Does anyone have any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: did you try to set image directly on xml <Image Source="mblogo.png" /> and working correctly?

Comment: Could be the case of your image. Try changing it to "mbmural.jpg" all lower case in both code and filename.

Comment: and also try to add width and height to image controller and see

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_1_-_android_resource_basics/) Xamarin article.
Android only support lowercase filename for resource items.
Please rename "MBMural.jpg" to all lowercase and have a try.

[image]